# Error code Missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed in R

Tags: r, if-statement, syntax

I keep getting this error message when I run my code, and I'm not sure what I need to do to fix it.

My code is as follows:

```
gwmh<-function(target,N,x,sigmasq){  
  p<-add.var()
  samples<-c(x,p)
  for(i in 2:N){
    prop<-rnorm(1,0,sqrt(sigmasq))
    if(runif(1)<min(1,(target(x+abs(prop)*p))/target(x))){
      x<-x+prop
    samples<-rbind(samples,c(x,p))} else{
      p<--p
    samples<-rbind(samples,c(x,p))
    }
  }
  samples[(1:N)]  ##delete after testing
}
```

The error says:
Error in if (runif(1) < min(1, (target(x + abs(prop) * p))/target(x))) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

(add.var is a function i created to generate p in {-1,1} randomly)

Comment: This means that the ```if(test_expression)``` tests an expressions that is neither TRUE or FALSE but missing. Have you checked that the data input into the function has no missing values?

Comment: And `target` is another one of your functions that you haven't provided? It's impossible to help unless you provide a lot more information. Obviously line 5 is the problem child.

Comment: @miasarah the error msg is saying that: the ```runif(1)<min(1,(target(x+abs(prop)*p))/target(x))``` this particular code is not evaluating to True or False. Ideally if conditions must have expression that evaluates to either T or F. Just debug the code written as condition. use `browser()` method before if condition to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I tested my comment and feel more comfortable offering it as an answer.

Try the following

```
if(TRUE){print("Test")}
# prints "Test"

if(FALSE){print("Test")}
# prints nothing

if(NA){print("Test")}
# throws your error
```

So within this expression:

```
runif(1)<min(1,(target(x+abs(prop)*p))/target(x))
```

the result is neither `TRUE` or `FALSE` but `NA`and seeing as `runif()`should not throw any missings it has to be in the rhs of the comparison.

Assuming that `target`, `x`, and `sigmasq` are all values from a df and not functions there is probably a missing value there. If this is the case and also intended you have to add an exception for catching and handling these missings that might look like this:

```
# test being your test expression
if(
  if(is.na(test) {Do Stuff for missing values}
  else {original IF statement}
```

Comment: Target is this function:
 
```target<-function(x){
  dnorm(x,0,1)
}
```

Comment: @miasarah so if Target doesn't have an error it should again only produce missing values if x contains them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `na.rm=TRUE` to the `min` function to account for possible NA in `x`.

Your function will fail if `x` contains NA.

```
target <- function(x) dnorm(x, 0, 1) 
add.var <- function() runif(1, -1, 1)

gwmh <- function(target,N,x,sigmasq){  
  p <- add.var()
  samples<-c(x,p)
  for(i in 2:N){
    prop<-rnorm(1,0,sqrt(sigmasq))
    if(runif(1) < min(1, (target(x+abs(prop)*p))/target(x), na.rm=TRUE)){  # <- Here
      x<-x+prop
      samples<-rbind(samples,c(x,p))} else{
        p<--p
        samples<-rbind(samples,c(x,p))
      }
  }
  samples[(1:N)]  ##delete after testing
}
```

Now try:

```
gwmh(target, N=2, x=c(1,2,NA,3), sigmasq=2)
# [1] 1.00 3.14
```